Проблема с установкой пакетов composer/php
Всем привет) Собственно не могу установить ни один пакет через композер, более того, не могу даже на сайт зайти, улетаю в таймаут.
У меня есть комп, обычный стационарный комп с 10 виндой, к которому интернет подключен по проводу. Проблем никаких нет, композер работает, пакеты ставит, сайт packagist открывается. Но, работаю я на ноутбуке, который к сети подключен через wifi. На самом ноуте 2 системы, винда 11 и рабочая ubuntu 20.04 и ни через одну систему я не могу достучаться до packagist'a. Пакеты так же установить не получается, получаю ошибку.
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file 
could not be downloaded: Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file 
could not be downloaded: SSL: Handshake timed out
Failed to enable crypto
Failed to open stream: operation failed

Нагуглил примерные решения проблемы, в общем ни одно не помогло. Более того, попытался через телефон зайти на packagist, вновь улетел в таймаут.
Но! стоит мне включить впн либо на ноуте(винда\убунту), либо на телефоне, так сразу все хорошо, и packagist работает и пакеты качает. Но блин, все время сидеть через впн тоже не дело. Такое чувство, как будто мой wifi блочит работу композера.
У меня билайн, позвонил в поддержку, сказали меняй роутер) Может была у кого нибудь похожая ситуация? А то как то странно менять роутер из-за того что он на некоторые сайты не пускает
